# How do I install Java in an ec2 instance?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, java-8

```
java -version
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

I am using this command but I get the error

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:52:13 ago on Fri Nov  3 16:57:25 2023.
No match for argument: java-1.8.0-openjdk
Error: Unable to find a match: java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

I am doing a kafka project on ec2 .

Comment: 1) Kafka supports Java 17. Please don't use 8 2) Use Amazon MSK and Kafka is automatically configured for you as a hosted service

Answer (score -1):

The error message `Unable to find a match: java-1.8.0-openjdk` means that the `yum` package manager cannot find the `java-1.8.0-openjdk` package in the repositories. This can happen if the package is not available in the repositories, or if the repositories are not configured correctly.

To fix this error, you can try the following:

1. Make sure that the repositories are configured correctly. You can do this by running the following command:

```
sudo yum repolist
```

This will list all of the repositories that are configured on your EC2 instance. Make sure that the repository that contains the `java-1.8.0-openjdk` package is listed.

2. If the repository is listed, try updating the repositories:

```
sudo yum update
```

This will update the package manager's knowledge of the repositories.

3. If the package is still not found, you can try installing it manually. You can download the `java-1.8.0-openjdk` RPM package from the Oracle website. Once you have downloaded the RPM package, you can install it using the following command:

```
sudo yum localinstall java-1.8.0-openjdk-*.rpm
```

Once the `java-1.8.0-openjdk` package is installed, you should be able to run the `java -version` command without any errors.

Here are some additional tips for installing Java on EC2:

- You can also use the Amazon Corretto distribution of OpenJDK, which is available in the Amazon Linux repositories. To install Corretto, run the following command:

```
sudo yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-11.0.5+10-1.amzn2.x86_64
```

Comment: Your (generated?) answer seems to have gotten confused that Java 8 was trying to be installed, and suggested using 11 instead, which does not solve the error. Also unclear why AWS support would help "installing Java". Please [see this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)